# How would you join two records that belong_to the same record without an N+1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've got an application in which businesses can file taxes and request tax extensions. (An extension is a request saying "I need more time to file.")

I have the following relationships:

```
Business has_many :tax_filings (one per year)
TaxFiling belongs_to :business

Business has_many :tax_extensions (one per year)
TaxExtension belongs_to :business
```

When I show a list of tax filings, I want each filing to show whether there is a corresponding extension for it. But I'm not sure how to do that without an N+1 query.

Right now I have this method on TaxFiling:

```
def extension
  TaxExtension.where(:business_id => business_id, :year => year).first
end
```

So every time I call `TaxFiling#extension`, it does another database query.

I added a scope for `TaxFiling` that `joins` extensions on `business_id` and `year`, but I'm not sure how to get `TaxFiling#extension` to use that without having a declared relationship between the two models.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe it seems obvious that one would query for businesses with a `joins` for both listings and extensions and go from there. But unfortunately, the listing and extension may belong to different users, neither of whom must own the business. So that won't work here.

Comment: I'm not sure, what users have to do with any of this?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - yeah, maybe that was more confusing than helpful. I was just trying to explain that there's an app-specific reason why I don't do `business.tax_filing` and `business.tax_extension` but instead have to traverse from the filing to the extension.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the `.includes` method, in order to do eager loading, when you initially load the TaxFiling models. If you do something like this:

```
TaxFiling.includes(:business => [:tax_extensions])
```

Rails will load the associated businesses and extensions into memory, using three queries (one per model), instead of N queries.

Comment: This looks like what I want. Is it possible to put a `where` on `tax_extensions` somehow, to ensure it's for the same year as the filing?

Comment: Absolutely. Once you've used `.includes` like that, you can refer to the included models just as if you'd joined them, so you can tack `.where('tax_extensions.year = tax_filings.year')` on there.